# Can I create a homescreen folder with a password lock through Swift?

Tags: swift

As the title states, I wish to create a folder on the homescreen (of an iphone) that allows you to store several apps of your own choice, just as you would normally do by dragging two apps into each other on an Iphone.  I want to lock this folder with a passcode.

I have searched for ages, but as far as I can tell, this has never been done before.

Answer (score 0):

At present iOS doesn't allow you to send commands to SpringBoard which is the application that manages the iOS home screen.

Maybe in the future but not today, sorry.